# Magnific Popup Uncaught TypeError: Property 'getImage' of object [object Object] is not a function

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="gallery">
  <div id="39" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf170c433d.png" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf170c433d_thumb.png" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="40" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1711a292.png" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1711a292_thumb.png" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="41" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1716b753.png" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1716b753_thumb.png" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="42" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf171afe23.jpg" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf171afe23_thumb.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="43" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf171cbbd4.jpg" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf171cbbd4_thumb.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="44" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf171ecfee.png" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf171ecfee_thumb.png" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="45" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf17232d77.jpg" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf17232d77_thumb.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="46" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1724fc13.jpg" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1724fc13_thumb.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
  <div id="47" class="box">
    <a href="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1725ef94.jpg" class="gallery-item">
      <img src="http://assets.avery.localhost/listing/gallery/10_529cf1725ef94_thumb.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" class="gallery-image">
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Then here is my jQuery for the magnific popup event:

```
$().ready(function () {
    $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: '.box a',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help!

Hmm I'm just confused because when I put it in this:
http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/JGjHK

It loads perfectly fine...

Comment: Here's an example the creator of the plugin made : http://codepen.io/dimsemenov/pen/JGjHK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are not including [magnific plugin](http://dimsemenov-static.s3.amazonaws.com/dist/jquery.magnific-popup.min.js) .

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#gallery').magnificPopup({
        type: 'image',
        delegate: '.box a',
        gallery: {
            enabled: true
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: No I am : <script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo __ASSET_PATH__ ?>/js/magnific-popup.js"></script> That's one line above the javascript that calls the function. And there is no 404 error. And when I click on it, it leads to the source file.

Comment: Because it's giving me this error : Uncaught TypeError: Property 'getImage' of object [object Object] is not a function magnific-popup.js:3

It's saying there is an actual error in the source file for magnific-popup.js

Comment: @Peanut can u make fiddle ?

Comment: @Peanut check all your script links on your site .

Comment: Nevermind you're right. I built it and forgot to include the image type... :/